# Calling a table of function using repeat blocks or macros in GNU assembly

Tags: c, assembly, macros, gnu-assembler

If I wanted to generate code that looks like this:

```
CALL FUNC0
CALL FUNC1
CALL FUNC2
CALL FUNC3
CALL FUNC4
CALL FUNC5
...
CALL FUNC19
```

How can I use a repeat block generate such code, using something similar to the code below:

```
.equ SYMBOL, 0
.rept 20
   CALL FUNC(SMYBOL)
   .equ SYMBOL, (SYMBOL+1)
.endr
```

Macros are fine too.

I'd like to know how to do this in C as well.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can use a macro do this:

```
.altmacro
.macro call_funcs count
    .if \count
        call_funcs %(count-1)
    .endif
    CALL    FUNC\count
.endm

call_funcs 20
```

The `.altmacro` directive enables the use of `%` to evaluate `count - 1` before passing recursively as a macro argument. Otherwise you get `CALL FUNC20-1-1-1-1` which not what you want.

As far as I know there's no way to what you want in C. For that I would write a program that generates the C code you need.

Comment: Thanks. I've found another way is to use `.irp`, although I have to actually write each value I want to generate like so: `.irp 0, 1, 2, ...`. This works well enough for what I'm doing.