# Using `.irp` with long list of value

Tags: assembly, riscv, gnu-assembler

Is there a way to use the [.irp](https://sourceware.org/binutils/docs/as/Irp.html) directive with a range of values rather than a list?

For example, when saving the context in RISC-V, one needs to store 31 registers to the context frame, like in

```
sw x1, 0*4(sp)
sw x2, 1*4(sp)
...
sw x31, 30*4(sp)
```

This can be replaced by `.irp` syntax:

```
.irp num 1,2,3,4,<more numbers>,31
 sw x\num, (num-1)*4(sp)
.endr
```

Is there any way to avoid providing the long list of explicit numbers and have something like range with start and end number instead?

Comment: @PeterCordes Yep. Just found this question: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/30764210/calling-a-table-of-function-using-repeat-blocks-or-macros-in-gnu-assembly `.altmacro` and recursive macro is the way to go.

Comment: GAS can use recursive macros, or a `.rept` loop with `.set i, i+1`

Comment: oh.. recursive .rept is interesting too

Comment: `.rept` isn't *recursive*, it's just iterating like NASM `%rep`.  Apparently `.set` inside it gets re-evaluated every iteration so you can use it like NASM `%assign`.

Comment: @PeterCordes I can't get the `set` symbol to evaluate with `%` (as in `%i`) for some reason. Recursive macro works though

Comment: Oh right, you need to get it as a string to paste with `x` as the register name, not *just* as the addressing-mode offset.  `sw x1, i*4(sp)` / `.set i, i+1` works for me with `clang -target riscv32`.  But I don't know how to stringify `i` in that case, in a `.rept` not a macro.